# How to change the color of the Choose File button (wordpress)?

Tags: css, wordpress, button, colors

I need to change the color of the `Choose File`.
I tried the following code, but it only changes `No file chosen`.
Would you please let me know how to change the color?

```css
.hide-if-value input {
  color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide-if-value">
  <label class="acf-basic-uploader">
        <input type="file" name="acf[field_60bc599999c5]" id="acf-field_60bc599999c5">
   </label>
</div>
```

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`::file-selector-button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button) since the upload button is part of the pseudo-element.

```css
.hide-if-value input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide-if-value">
  <label class="acf-basic-uploader">
            <input type="file" name="acf[field_60bc599999c5]" id="acf-field_60bc599999c5">
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello: Wow, thank you for your help. I added input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button, and it changed the color. Thanks agaon :)

Comment: @Fioi Cool. The WebKit version may work on some of the browsers and not all: https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Afile-selector-button So you can change it to non-webkit version. Also, your code will turn all the "Upload files" button to red unless you want it to be specific inside another parent.

Comment: Hi m4n0: Oh, wow, I didn't know that. I've learnt a lot from you. Thank you for sharing and I will try to find non-webkit solution, as ::file-selector-button didn't change the color in chrome. Thank you again m4n0 : )

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code.

`input[type=file]::file-selector-button {color: #069e08; }`

Comment: Hello: thank you for your help. I got an idea from your advice and I added input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button, and it changed the color. Thanks agaon :)